# Own output stream (mock cout)

Tags: c++, io, std, ostream

This is a sample C++ code

```
ostream& log = cout;
ostream& getLog() { return log; }

// somewhere in code
getLog() << "Message";
```

When this code executes, the "Message" gets printed.

**Q:** What is the easiest way to discard those messages (don't print them, don't save them)? `getLog` must still be used by clients, but could return some mocked output stream that swallows all messages...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the following horror:

```
ostream nullstream(0);
ostream& log = nullstream;
```

Passing null to the constructor of `ostream` will set the `badbit` flag and therefore discard all writes.

Comment: looks nice! this is portable? can it be a static variable?

Comment: @Queequeg: My answer on the duped question goes into detail on why that's safe.

Comment: Why "horror"? It is "working as designed"!

Comment: It cannot be used with functions that check write status, as the badbit will be telling that writing failed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [similar post that attempts to do this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t284398-is-there-a-null-ostream-like-dev-null-in-cpp.html) - the cpp way to emulate redirecting to `/dev/null`

> > Is it easy to implement one?
>
> Yes. Derive a class from std::streambuf and override the protected
>   virtual function overflow as follows
>
> int overflow(int c) { return c; }
>
> Then you can use a standard istream and set its stream buffer to an
>   instance of your streambuf class using rdbuf. Or you can define your
>   own derived ostream class which automatically uses an an instance of
>   your streambuf class.

Comment: I think this would have been better off as a comment.

Comment: @Rapptz: It answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick an dirty:**

Define a class that derive from std::ostream and that implements the `<<` operator for whatever T doing nothing.

Unfortunately this may not work in some cases: the `<<` operator in `std::ostream` isn't polymorphic (not virtual), hence your overridden `<<` will be called only when the stream type is `yourstream&` and not `std::ostream&`.

**More polite**:

derive `std::streambuf`, with a class that has no buffer, and that overrides **[overlflow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow)** by **always return 0**.

Then create an `std::ostream` associated with that buffer, and return it from your getLog();

This will let `ostream` to play its job: convert values into text and send characters to the buffer. The buffer will just eat them without doing anything.

Polite for the library, not so efficient, being the `ostream` value-to-text routines called in any case.

**The most efficient**:

is make the compilation of logging statements conditinal: like

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DBG(x) x
#else
#define DBG(x)
#endif

// Your entire code here

#undef DBG
```

and write logging as

```
DBG(std::cout << logging_variables_and_text << std::endl);
```

When `DEBUG` is not defined, everything in `DBG` will be wiped out (and no CPU cycles will be anymore spent)